# Do I really need cdn for video delivery?

Tags: cdn, video, video-streaming

If I'm going to create video delivery site for big country (Russia), should I use CDN for video?
I believe, that store video in two places, Tokyo (for East part of country) and Frankfurt (for West part of country) for example much cheaper than load videos to CDN. However, I'm a bit worry about video load speed, but should I?

#### UPD.

Sorry I'm not really good in this kind of questions. So, as for the tecnical details.

I suppose that, it's will be quite big service. Most part of users based in one country. Our own servers output speed about 220Gb/s.

From answer below, I understand that most likely I'll need cdn, but what parameters should I keep in mind while choosing?

Comment: @mfinni, sorry but my question haven't any similar with this question

Comment: It does, because as Chopper3 says below, it entirely depends on details particular to your setup, and the only way to find these out is to run your own tests.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Do I really need cdn for video delivery?

"It depends". It depends on where your users are, how many there are of them, what's their concurrency needs, if your infrastructure can deliver what's needed on its own and how much you want to spend on delivery.

You really need to understand these factors before deciding if a CDN works for you. As an example say you only have a few users who won't be likely to all want to play a video at the same time then you can probably get away without a CDN. If you have thousands+ of users, all playing video at random times and from a variety of ISP's then a CDN is very likely to be needed.

Basically you need to know your audience first before making a technical decision.

Comment: I made several clarifications.

Comment: Thanks for the update, really all you need to do is to pick a CDN that can a) do what you functionally need and b) is within your budget and c) has service you're happy with. We don't do product/service selection help here though sorry.